# Invalid Value Error in RoR GMaps app - without code change

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I sat down to work on my google maps RoR map and it suddendly stopped working today. Both my local repository and the heroku "production" app are not displaying google maps. Both are giving me error in chrome console :

> InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with >finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value

I've looked around but most responses seem to be connected to the malformed LatLong data while specifying center. I am doing no such thing. Relevant code snippet:

```
function init(){

      handler = Gmaps.build('Google')

      var map = handler.buildMap(
        { 
          provider: {
                zoom: 4,
                maxZoom: 15,
                minZoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
            },
            internal: {id: 'map'}
            }, function(){
              handler.getMap().addListener( 'click', function(e){
              console.log('Click!')
              laceMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, handler.getMap());
      })
(...)
```

I'd be very thankful for either solution or workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem here when developing a plugin on Wordpress using Google Map.

**Steps to reproduce:**
Open map on Firefox open the inspector.
Activate the mobile display.
Enable touch simulation.
Reload the page.
Click on the map to move around.

**Expected result:**
The map moves around and displays the markers.

**Actual result:**

> The map freezes and an error is displayed on each click on the map
>   trough the terminal: InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or
>   LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an
>   accepted value

[Screenshot of the Google Chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COHJp.png)

**Traceback:**
[Screenshot of the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dYb6.png)

**Clue to investigate:**

There must be an error in the update of the file https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/37/10a/intl/en_au/common.js line 71

Answer (score 1):

I think this was (is) an issue with a google map update. I was experiencing the same issue yesterday (25/7/19) but it seems ok now.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for posting. Any idea on the details of what happened? Scared the crap out of me

Answer (score 0):

in my case its because variable Latitude and Longitude is undefined when using latLng to panTo the map.